# looking for function , f:[-1,1]->[-1,1] continuous everywhere, infinitely smooth a.e. , f(1)=1=-f(-1) and has nth derivative 0 at -1 and 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am looking for an odd function , f:[-1,1]->[-1,1] that is infinitely smooth everywhere , f(1)=1=-f(-1) and has an kth derivative of 0 at -1 and 1 for all k$\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I started out by trying to represent the issue as a power series of the form

$\sum^{\infty}_{1} a_{n} x^{2n-1}$ from which we get 
$\sum^{\infty}_{1} a_{n}=1$ and for all k>0
$\sum^{\infty}_{\lceil{k/2}\rceil} a_{n} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n-1-k)!}=0$

but I have no good way to solve these problems

edit: $C^\infty$ everywhere, not almost everywhere

Comment: I don't think a power series will work.  If all derivatives at $1$ are zero, then expanding in a power series around $a=1$ will result in the zero function.

Comment: well, that would just mean that around 0 the radius of convergence is at most 1 right? its not necessarily a problem yet

Answer (score 1):

Start with an infinitely differentiable function with all derivatives at origin equal to zero. (I believe $f(x) = e^{-\frac 1 {x^2}}$ for $x \ne 0$, $f(0) = 0$ is an example.) Then take something like $h(x) = 1 - cf(1+x) f(1-x)$. Choose the constant $c>0$ so that the image is in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: the function you posted would be even, not odd. plug in -x for x and you get the same function. but maybe something can be done with this

Comment: @Alosapien - Oh, you are right, I missed a minus sign in the OP's question. In any case - starting with $f$ and then combining translations and reflections of it is the general idea; the OP should be able to use this for his ends.

Comment: that might cause issues with $C^\infty$

Comment: @Alosapien - Why? $f(x)\cdot(1-f(x-1))$ is $\cal C^{\infty}$, it is zero at the origin and strictly positive at 1, and all derivatives are zero at both $x=0$ and $x=1$. Then reflect this in the origin for the other half of the function. What issues might arise?

Comment: yup, okay this will work